# remove_if comparing two elements in the same vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector of objects. Lets call them "myObj". I need to run through the vector of myObj and determine if the current object interacts with another myObj in that vector and remove both objects if either has interacted with the other.

```
for (std::vector<myObj*>::iterator it = objects.begin(); it < objects.end(); ++it)
{
    myObj*& r1 = (*it);
    myObj*& r2 = (*(it + 1));
    if ( r1->interactsWith(r2) )
    {
        objectInteracted(r1);
        objectInteracted(r2);
        delete r1;
        delete r2;
        r1 = NULL;
        r2 = NULL;
        ++it;
    }
}

objects.erase(std::remove(objects.begin(), objects.end(), NULL), objects.end()); //Causing "no conversion from const int to myObj"
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use the remove-erase idiom to clear these objects out of the vector. However, when trying to compile, I get an error: "C2446 '==': no conversion from 'const int' to 'myObj *'

I would much prefer to use the remove_if function but since my predicate would need to take in and compare two elements in the same vector, I have no idea how to correctly construct the predicate. Could someone either tell me why I'm getting the compilation error, or show me how to construct a correct predicate for the above? I've Google for hours and have found no examples whatsoever that show predicates with more complex behaviour than, say, removing odd numbers from a list which naturally doesn't require any input except the element currently being tested.

Comment: Use a debugger and right an appropriate comment in the line that is causing the error. It will be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: Is using C++11 an option?

Comment: Sorry, added the comment now. The line causing the compilation error is the objects.erase(...) line

Comment: He's actually not removing elements from a vector inside the loop.

Comment: Nemanja Boric, if C++11 has the appropriate functionality it is indeed an option.

Comment: is `interactsWith()` symmetric? That is, `a.interactsWith(b) === b.interactsWith(a)`. Additionally, if `a` interacts with `b` and `b` interacts with `c`, should `{a, b, c}` be removed? Also, I assume that if the vector is `[a,b,c]` and `a` interacts with `c`, then `{a, c}` should be removed, even though they are not neighbors in the vector.

Comment: Can the order of the vector be somewhat randomized after this operation? Or should the remaining elements be in the original order (modulo removals)? _(Should this operation be stable?)_

Comment: The order of the objects within the vector isn't important. The vector isn't sorted in any way so the order of the objects is going to be random before and after the operation, so unfortunately the comparison process needs to be done with the assumption the vector is not ordered.

Comment: also sharth, interactsWith() is symmetric and for any object that interacts with another, both objects in the interaction should be removed. if a interacts with b and b with c, all three should be removed (I believe my code above bears this out).

Comment: @user2087530: As far as I can tell, your code would fail in the case `[a,b,c]` where only `a` and `c` interact.

Comment: @user2087530: Is it also commutative? That is, if `a` interacts with `b`, and `b` interacts with `c`, then `a` __must__ interact with `c`?

Comment: Its not commutative. In any interaction, the only objects you can assume have interacted are the two that have been checked. a->b and b->c doesn't imply c->a if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I don't believe that your current code works for all cases. And therefore, I think it needs a larger fix.

For example, let's assume that you have 3 objects in your vector, and all 3 of them interact. Your code will grab the first two, and then remove them. When we get to the third, there won't be anything for it to interact with, so it will remain. **But that's not correct behavior**.

I've written some code that works as follows:

- We take the vector, and hold a `start` and `end` position. These iterators represent the valid remaining area to work over.
- Three areas within our vector:

  - Elements between `[vec.begin(), start)` are objects that we know we will keep, and have compared them already against everything in the vector. So we don't need to touch them any more.
  - Elements between `[start, end)`, are elements that we still need to compare things against to see if they have any interactions.
  - Elements between `[end, vec.end())` are elements that we know are interacting with other things. However, there may still be **more** elements that they interact with that we haven't found yet.
- Our end condition is when `start == end`. This works because at this point, there are no more elements to compare for interactions.

#### Code Follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct myObj {
    myObj(int val): val(val) {}

    bool interactsWith(struct myObj *other) {
        return this->val == other->val;
    }

    const int val;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<myObj *> vec;
    vec.push_back(new myObj(3));
    vec.push_back(new myObj(2));
    vec.push_back(new myObj(1));
    vec.push_back(new myObj(2));

    // Print the vector
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x->val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto start = vec.begin();
    auto end = vec.end();

    while (start != end) {
        // Test if start interacts with anything in the vector
        std::vector<myObj *>::iterator match;
        for (match = start + 1; match != vec.end(); ++match)
            if ((*start)->interactsWith(*match))
                break;

        // We did not find a match
        if (match == vec.end()) {
            start++;
            continue;
        }

        // If the match isn't already in the removal area, move it there.
        if (match < end)
            std::iter_swap(match, --end);

        // The start is always before the removal area, so move it there.
        std::iter_swap(start, --end);
    }

    // Print the vector
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x->val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Delete the memory backing these elements
    // We should probably just be using std::vector<std::unique_ptr>>...
    std::for_each(end, vec.end(), [](myObj * & obj) {
        delete obj;
        obj = NULL;
        });

    // Remove the elements from the vector
    vec.erase(end, vec.end());

    // Print the vector
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x->val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

This will output:

```
[4:04pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] ./foo
3 2 1 2   // The original vector
3 1 2 2   // The elements that intersect have been moved to the back of the vector
3 1       // We've erased those elements from the vector.
```

#### And a note:

This ends up being very similar to [NicholasM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589937/47453) with a few optimizations that are not presant in his.

- Once we find an element does not intersect with anything, we can ignore it.
- When we find an intersecting match, we can move both elements to the end of the list.

Both of these optimizations are allowed because `intersectsWith()` is associative.

Comment: You were absolutely right, I overlooked the fact that my code would have worked incorrectly. Thanks for pointing it out:).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `NULL` is being passed to the `std::remove` as a integer, and not as a pointer. If using C++11 is an option, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` (both in your `for` loop and inside `std::remove`). If it isn't, cast `NULL` to the appropriate type:

```
objects.erase(std::remove(objects.begin(), objects.end(), static_cast<myObj*>(NULL)), 
              objects.end()); //Causing "no conversion from const int to myObj"
```

Comment: This was the simplest way to fix my existing code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your problem description, it sounds like you need a predicate that tests whether the given object interacts with ANY other object in the vector.

In other words, it sounds like you need a `std::remove_if` with `std::find_if` as part of its predicate.

The approach below uses a lambda function, and thus requires C++11.  You could avoid this with a simple for loop in `InteractionChecker::operator()`.

```
typedef std::vector<myObj*> ObjectVector;
struct InteractionChecker
{
  InteractionChecker(const ObjectVector& objects) : m_objects(objects) {}

  // Return 'true' iff checked_obj interacts with any object in m_objects.
  bool operator()(const myObj* checked_obj)
  {
    // Need to think about whether checked_obj interacts with itself
    return m_objects.end() != std::find_if(m_objects.begin(), m_objects.end(),
                                           [checked_obj](myObj* other)
                                           { 
                                               return checked_obj->interactsWith(other); 
                                           });
  } 

private:
  const ObjectVector& m_objects;
};

ObjectVector objects;
// Populate objects vector.

InteractionChecker checker(objects);
std::remove_if(objects.begin(), objects.end(), checker);
```

Comment: This is excellent, but on reflection, the above answer meets my needs nicely. Upvoted anyway.